# 'Not Found: /' error when linking app urls.py to project's urls.py

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble linking to an app's urls.py file in Django

**first_project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first_app', include('first_app.urls')),
]
```

**first_app urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Error**

```
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'first_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /
[31/Mar/2019 14:28:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2038
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a trailing slash to `first_app` url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your ***URL configuration***, you should've access the following url,
**`/first_app/`**
Eg: http://localhost/first_app/